# Forced root of monic integer polynomial given that all roots are real, lie between 0 and 3 and one of them is irrational

Tags: polynomials

I have no idea what the source of this problem is (maybe Brilliant?  Before it became not itself?).  I stole it from somewhere and it has been sitting in my archive.  I know I dumbed it down to a simpler version before putting it in the archive:

> Let $Q$ be a monic quadratic with integer coefficients such that its roots are real, lie in the interval $(0,3)$, and such that at least one root is irrational.  Show that $Q\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)=0$.

This is not too bad.  But what I think is the original problem, the generalization, seems much harder.

> Let $P$ be a monic polynomial with integer coefficients such that its roots are real, lie in the interval $(0,3)$, and such that at least one root is irrational.  Show that $P\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)=0$.

As a consequence of my poor memory, this may not even be necessarily true.  I think the generalization definitely included arbitrary degree, monic, and the interval $(0,3)$ though.

As for progress, it is clear to me that if there exists a root of the form $\frac{a+\sqrt{b}}{2}$ then the result should follow by some number theory and casework.  But the roots may not look so nice, and could surely look quite hideous.

Some manual searching with Desmos suggests that the generalization works at least for cubics.

Any proofs, disproofs, thoughts, or complaints would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This seems insane, and is very fascinating. I've checked it for quartics, that was fast when done properly. I may do quintics next.

If the conjecture is true, it means that *any* such polynomial is a product of factors (x-1), (x-2) and (x^2-3x+1). Alternatively, one could say that the minimal degree counterexample has no such factors.

Comment: I've now checked every degree up to 11, and found no counterexamples. My code finds $x^3-5x^2+6x-1$ if you allow roots up to 3.25.

Comment: no counterexamples of degree 12 or 13 either, but each new degree takes exponentially longer. 

I tried this approach: given the polynomial p(x) is zero at n points within (0,3), and |p(x)| is at least 1 at x=0,1,2,3 (since it's an integer), what bounds does this place on the nth derivative of p(x)? The algebra got very messy quickly though, but there's probably a better approach than the one I tried (which was to directly work it out).

Comment: For example, divided differences give a specific higher derivative based on values at certain points: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences

Comment: Some people I know are suggesting to use discriminants of number fields, though I'm not sure how any of that would work (and my grasp of abstract algebra is horrifyingly bad).

Comment: My first thoughts were along those lines, but I don't know enough to see how to incorporate conditions like the fact that all the roots are between 0 and 3

Comment: I've now checked degree 14 and 15, and was not surprised to find no counterexamples.